# Hiding child elements in a responsive/percentage-based layout?

Tags: html, css, overflow

**Consider this HTML**:

```
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus sapien congue, fringilla justo quis, aliquam tellus. Maecenas semper consectetur metus eget varius. Curabitur imperdiet sagittis leo, a mollis dui lobortis in. In ac facilisis tortor. Nam vitae pellentesque lorem, non commodo lacus.
    <div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The aim here is to try and have the parent `div` hide the child `div` with `overflow:hidden`. But the intended use is to animate/change the parent `div` width to 'reveal' the child's content. To be clear, I don't need the animation/change code for this purpose. I simply need a solid base of HTML/CSS such that it will be possible to animate/change at runtime while retaining these original rules:

- the parent must be a percentage width of the screen (with the intention of animating its width in order to reveal/hide its child).
- the child must also be a percentage width of the screen.
- the child must not wrap its contents according to its parent.
- the parent should only reveal as much as the child as it can given its width.
- No absolute widths in pixels.
- No CSS3.
- No JavaScript.

---

**Example**:

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: aims]

In this example, only the parent `div` section of the child `div` should be viewable. But the child's content shouldn't wrap, and both the parent and the child should be percentage widths of the screen.

---

**What I've Tried**:

So far, I've attempted with this CSS:

```
html, body{

  height:100%;

}

#parent{

  position:relative;

  width:15%;
  height:100%;

  overflow:hidden;

}

#child{

  position:absolute;

  width:200%;

}
```

The problem with the CSS above is that the child `div` is constantly adjusting its `width` according to its parent `div`, so 'revealing' the child `div` by increasing the percentage width of its parent is virtually impossible until the childs content has 'unwrapped' itself fully.

---

**You May Ask**:

- *Why not remove `position:relative` from the parent so that the child width remains consistent to the screen?*

Because in order to hide an absolutely positioned child element, the parent needs to have its position set to `relative`.

- *Why not make the child element `static` or `relative`?*

Because then the content of the child wraps according to its parent, making it impossible to 'hide' anything.

- *Why is the child at 200%?*

So that it can have a relative width (to the screen) of 30%. Because the parent is 15%, the child needs to be double its parents percentage width in order to achieve a 30% fill of the screen.

- *Can we use absolute widths in pixels?*

No.

- *Can we use CSS3?*

No.

- *Can we use JavaScript?*

No. If we could use JavaScript, I wouldn't be asking this question, I'd be in the pub. :-)

Comment: I know its not an answer for you, because you can't use CSS3 or JS,
but for other who wonders to this post and can, visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936352/hiding-child-elements-with-percentage-widths) for answers.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/cxUnK/1/)

Comment: @Itay Have you tried animating the parent width out to 'reveal' the childs content?

Comment: @Itay You misunderstand me. No I don't want a bunch of arbitrary animation code. I was just wanting to highlight the behaviour of the `div`s for you by asking you to open your developers console and play with the parent's `width`...

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly are you trying to do, even after reading your question twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find a workaround, I have come with this posibility:

You will need an extra wrapper:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="parent2">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then this CSS

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    left: -70%;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.parent2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    left: 70%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent, .parent2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300");
    background-size: cover;
}

.parent:hover {
    left: -40%;
}

.parent:hover .parent2 {
    left: 40%;
}
```

You implement a "sliding window" technique. The parent doesn't really grow, the 2 parents change position to allow more or less of the child to be seen.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guuha/1/)

The transition is already implemented on hover.
Also, you get rid of the artificial calculus of the width of the child.

Comment: The time of need has long-passed, but this is an ingenious way of solving the issue with the specified requirements. Well done for putting the time in, I'm sure this will be useful in future projects.